# How to get durability out of PushSharp

Tags: database, notifications, persistence, pushsharp

I am using Ms Sql Server with PushSharp in ASP MVC, I understand the server side objects in pushsharp 3.0.

How does one go about getting durability from this component. For e.g. a persistent queue survives restarts,

**How do the message survive a restart/reboot**, is there datatstore mechanism for PushStrap, how is it configured? or restarted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no data storage or concept of persistent queues in PushSharp.  This will be up to you to implement.  Of course there are many ways you could do this, one idea would be to store notifications to be sent in a database, and mark them completed once PushSharp returns a successful status for their sending.

Persistence is a fairly opinionated subject and not something I am going to introduce into PushSharp.